# Return last occurrence of True in series of dtype bool

Tags: pandas

If using the following series:

```
sodf = pd.Series([9,10,10,9,10,10])
sodf

0     9
1    10
2    10
3     9
4    10
5    10
dtype: int64
```

And then returning a bool series:

```
sodf == 9

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

How do I return a bool series but only with the last (highest row index number) occurrence of 9?

**Desired output:**

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
mask = sodf == 9
out = mask[::-1].cumsum().eq(1) & mask
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```